# git check-ignore outputting unignored files

Tags: git, github, gitignore

The file `https://github.com/tanafaso/tanafaso-frontend/blob/master/lib/net/api_interface/azkar/requests/get_categories_response.dart` is not ignored by git, and that's expected as I have only listed `azkar/` in `.gitignore` which means that only the directory `azkar/` under the root should be ignored.

However, `git check-ignore` thinks that the file will be ignored and that it satisfies the pattern `azkar/`.

```
➜  azkar-frontend git:(master) ✗ git check-ignore --verbose lib/net/api_interface/azkar/requests/get_categories_response.dart
.gitignore:20:azkar/    lib/net/api_interface/azkar/requests/get_categories_response.dart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format :

> If there is a separator at the end of the pattern then the pattern will only match directories, otherwise the pattern can match both files and directories.

Nothing is said about directory level unlike

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore…

Hence the pattern `azkar/` matches any directory "azkar" deep in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: You are right! Unfortunately, I didn't notice that because I added the file to git first and in a later commit, I added the .gitignore line.

Comment: @OmarYasser If you want to ignore it: `git rm -r --cached tanafaso-frontend/blob/master/lib/net/api_interface/azkar && git commit -m "Remove azkar"` : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/7976758